# Android MotionEvent onTouch jumps even if my finger is still in one point

Tags: java, android, device, ontouchlistener

recently i try to use the ontouch event on a view, and i realise that the X axis jumps over 5 or 10 pixels ramdomly even when my finger is still, is a hardware issue? i read that the ontouch move event is imprecise then i want to know how i can do it precise.

```
case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

    lastmovex = (int) event.getX();
    lastmovey = (int) event.getY();

    break;

case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

    int x = (int) event.getX(pointerindex) - lastmovex;
    int y = (int) event.getY(pointerindex) - lastmovey;
    Log.d(TAG,"move x="+x+" y="+y);
    break;
```

this show me (on finger still in one point):

```
move x=0 y=0
move x=-2 y=0
move x=0 y=0
move x=1 y=0
move x=-5 y=0
move x=3 y=0
move x=1 y=0
move x=0 y=0
```

so, how i can get more precision or is my device with that problem? Thanks for your help

Comment: From what I know there is no problem. Are you perhaps using a big screen? 1 pixel is very, very small on a big device and you cannot keep completely still because you breath. If you are going to measure it would be best to use DPI instead of pixels; you convert the input to DPI and measure that. Which phone have you tried on?

Comment: i have using a tablet 7 inch upad, thanks for your answer, how i can convert the pixels into dpi? or how i can measure for example the size of the finger?

Answer (score 1):

```
int x = (int) (event.getX(pointerindex) * event.getXPrecision()  - lastmovex);
int y = (int) (event.getY(pointerindex) * event.getXPrecision()  - lastmovey);
```

Try to measure with this ?

Comment: i tried it but getXPrecision() returns me 0.0 so does not works